# addParameter to raster in Python QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I create a plugin for processing two rasters. I want to set two input layers and one output layer.

```
class CombineRaster:

"""QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    Input = 'Input raster'
    Input2 = 'Input second raster'
    Output = 'Output'


def __init__(self, iface):
     self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(
         self.Input,
         self.tr("Input raster"), None, False))
     self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(
         self.Input2,
         self.tr("Input second raster"), None, False))
     self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(
         self.Output,
         self.tr("Output"),
         None, False))
```

When loading the plugin, I get an AttributeError error: 'CombineRaster' (my plugin) object has no attribute 'addParameter'. What is wrong?

Comment: Your `__init__` references `addParameter` but doesn't define it. If you want to inherit from a parent class, you need to reference that at class declaration.

Comment: Your `CombineRaster` class needs to inherit from `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` to be able to use the `addParameter()` method. Otherwise Python won't know you're creating a Processing algorithm and will trigger the error you've got. You can also think what is more appropriate for your use case. For instance, you could create a Processing script instead of a plugin. QGIS gives you a template for writing Processing scripts. It will help you a lot at the beginning. Go to `Create New Script from Template...` from the Processing Toolbox.